# How to call Asp.net MVC page from Asp.net normal page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have Asp.net application.
I want to integrate another Asp.net MVC application to exsting Asp.net application.

So I did the following changes.

1.I added area in exsting Asp.net application.
2.Added path in routeconfig.
3.Now How to call Asp.net MVC Razor ??

Controller Name-Home
Action Name-Home

How to call Home page inside MVC Area from js file present in asp.net project.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's same as calling other page.. just you set up the proper routing structure in order to render the view.

```
document.location.href='yourArea/FolderName/Home/Action';
```

or you can use an HyperLink to achieve the same

```
<a href="yourURlTOMvcView">MVC view </a>
```

Comment: But I have another question, If let say, existing asp.net app has master page and and i am using same master page in MVC also, using iframe, then using this call document.location.href='yourArea/FolderName/Home/Action' , will the session for both existing asp.net app and MVC will be the same. I want such a call from Asp to MVC that, in both case, session will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to call method, then simple way is  Response.Redirect("~/ControllerName/ActionMethodName");